# Postgresql - Pgadmin: Insert json file into table

Tags: python, json, pandas, pgadmin

I would like to push a json file into a table on PgAdmin. I created the table with asks-bids-lastUpdated as column but PgAdmin does not accept normaly the json format. My json file looks like this:

```
[
{ 
    "asks" : [
        [
            0.00276477, 
            9
        ], 
        [
            0.00276478, 
            582
        ], ]
    "bids" : [
        [
            0.00276477, 
            9
        ], 
        [
            0.00276478, 
            582
        ], 
, 
    "lastUpdated" : 1538582700048.0
}]
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=monty user=postgres host=localhost password=******")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("COPY orderbook FROM '/home/viktor/code/Keyrock/orderbook.json' CSV HEADER;")
```

Can someone help me please? I am really stuck and have no clue on how to do it...